# Calling a method in another class from a matplotlib's custom toolbar's button

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

I'm using `PyQt` and `Matplotlib` libraries to create an application. I've created a sub-class of my `QMainWindow` and I do not know how to connect the method of the new class to the methods in the first class.

At first, I created a `QPushButton` in the `QMainWindow` like this:

```
class A(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    QMainWindow.__init__(self)

    self.mainWidget = QWidget()
    self.setCentralWidget(self.mainWidget)

    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    self.mainWidget.setLayout(layout)

    self.figure_canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure(facecolor="lightblue"))
    layout.addWidget(self.figure_canvas, 10)

    self.axes = self.figure_canvas.figure.add_subplot(111)

    #Here is the first button creatd and added to the navigation toolbar
    #using addWidget
    self.btn_selection_tool = QPushButton(QIcon("select.png"), "")
    self.navigation_toolbar.addWidget(self.btn_selection_tool)

    #And here is how i connected this button to two methods
    self.connect(self.btn_selection_tool, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.method1)
    self.connect(self.btn_selection_tool, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.method2)
```

But now, I had to create a new class (class B) and I need to connect a method from this one to the methods called before by the `QPushButton` in `class A`. But, in this case, I do not have a button to do it. I just need to "trigger" this methods in `class A` , by a method in `class B`.

My problem is that I can not call the methods in `class A` (self.method1 and  self.method2)the same way that I did when I created the `QPushbutton`. This is before creating the subclass.

I've tried doing:

```
def method_in_B_class(self):
  self.a  = A()
  self.a.method1()
  self.a.method2()
```

How can I do this? Hope you can help me.

### ------ EDIT -----

These are the two methods:

```
def method1(self):
    self.figure_canvas.setCursor(Qt.IBeamCursor)
    self.selection_mode = None
    #self.selectionmode is a variable that I change when method1 is called
    #and I can go through the "if" in method2

def method2(self):
    #I define some conditions with another variables
    if len(self.axes.lines) >= 1 and self.selection_mode == None and A.send_msg == None:

        self.cid_press = self.figure_canvas.mpl_connect("button_press_event", self.method3)
        self.cid_release = self.figure_canvas.mpl_connect("button_release_event", self.method4)

    elif self.selection_mode == "disable":
        self.disconnect(self)
```

So, when they are called using:

```
def method_in_B_class(self):
  self.a  = A()
  self.a.method1()
  self.a.method2()
```

they are instantiated, but then they are "finished" we might say. This is that the `QtCursor` does not change, and the `method3` and `method4` are not called.

Comment: Should probably pass through `parent=parent`.

Comment: `NavigationToolbar2.__init__(self, figure_canvas, parent= None)` -> `NavigationToolbar2.__init__(self, figure_canvas, parent=parent)` but I think that is unrelated to your problem.

Comment: and I would look at the code `matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5.py` to see how the toolbar gets built.  Is the problem that 'bye' is not being called or something else?

Comment: I've tried that, an it is not the problem. Sorry, I did not understand. The problem is that when the `method1` and `method2` are called, they do not "act" like when I call them using the `QPushButton`.

Comment: Probably because you are calling them directly, not invoking them via slots/signals.  You are also creating a new instance of `A`.  You probably should have your custom toolbar have a signal that you can then connect to the slot on `A` and emit on in `bye`.

Comment: I edited the question to  explain myself better. Hope this helps

Comment: Everytime you call `bye` you are creating a new instance of `A` (your whole window) and operating on _that_ instance.

Comment: What should I do then?

Comment: Either use signals/slots to connect out or pass a ref to A into your toolbar (I strongly suspect that it comes in as parent)